# Shifting center image's position to left in WaterWheel Carousel

Tags: jquery

```
  movedToCenter: function ($item) {
        $('.carousel-center').css({ left: "300px" });
```

I have tried moving image using above code, but it shows jumping effect.

Comment: Can you give a jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle?? I am complete newbie to jquery can u plz elaborate your point

Comment: copy and paste your codes into jsfiddle.net and show us what have you tried.